# Highchart always download PNG images?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I combined two charts together to export both charts.

```
<script defer="true"><![CDATA[
     (function(){
        var exportChart = function() {
            Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
                var svgArr = [], top = 0, width = 0;

                jq.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
                    var svg = chart.getSVG();
                    svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top
                            + ')" ');
                    svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                    top += chart.chartHeight;
                    width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

                    svgArr.push(svg);
                });

                return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width
                        + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
                        + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
            };

            Highcharts.exportCharts = function() {
                var charts = [];
                jq(".test-timeline-chart .highcharts-container")
                        .each(
                                function(i, e) {
                                    charts
                                            .push(Highcharts.charts[jq(e).parent()
                                                    .data().highchartsChart]);
                                });
                var form;
                svg = Highcharts.getSVG(charts);

                // merge the options
                var options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, {});

                // create the form
                form = Highcharts.createElement('form', {
                    method : 'post',
                    action : options.url
                }, {
                    display : 'none'
                }, document.body);

                // add the values
                Highcharts.each([ 'filename', 'type', 'width', 'svg' ], function(name) {
                    Highcharts.createElement('input', {
                        type : 'hidden',
                        name : name,
                        value : {
                            filename : options.filename || 'chart',
                            type : options.type,
                            width : options.width,
                            svg : svg
                        }[name]
                    }, null, form);
                });
                // submit
                form.submit();

                // clean up
                form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
            };

            // printing all the charts in single page.
            function printAll() {

                var origDisplay = [], origParent = [], body = document.body, childNodes = body.childNodes;

                // hide all body content
                Highcharts.each(childNodes, function(node, i) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        origDisplay[i] = node.style.display;
                        node.style.display = "none";
                    }
                });

                var charts = [];
                jq(".test-timeline-chart .highcharts-container")
                        .each(
                                function(i, e) {
                                    charts
                                            .push(Highcharts.charts[jq(e).parent()
                                                    .data().highchartsChart]);
                                });
                // put the charts back in
                jq.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
                    origParent[i] = chart.container.parentNode;
                    body.appendChild(chart.container);
                });

                // print
                window.print();

                // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // put the chart back in
                    jq.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
                        origParent[i].appendChild(chart.container);
                    });

                    // restore all body content
                    Highcharts.each(childNodes, function(node, i) {
                        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                            node.style.display = origDisplay[i];
                        }
                    });
                }, 500);
            }

             if(jq(".test-timeline-chart").length > 0) {
                var index = jq(".test-timeline-chart .highcharts-container:first").parent().data().highchartsChart; 
                var instanceChart = Highcharts.charts[index+1];
                instanceChart.exportChart = Highcharts.exportCharts;
                instanceChart.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems[0].onclick = function() {
                    printAll();
                };
             };
        };
        exportChart();  
      })();

     ]]>
     </script>
```

The  `var options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, {});` always returing the PNG image and the export chart option always download PNG images. How I can fix this?

I found a way to listen to the `onclick` event of high chart context menu items. Is there a way to get selected items?

Comment: If you don' want to download the PNG image then what else do you need to download? Can you create a DEMO of your code?

Comment: I think you want to use [menuItems](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) and [menuItemDefinitions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions) where you can define your own callback with predefined `type`. Something like this: `exporting: { menuItemDefinitions: { myPDF: { onclick: function () { exportChart('pdf'); } } } }`  and simply change `type : options.type,` to `type: myType`, where `myType` is available from `var exportChart = function(myType) { ... };`.